# uncaught throw :warden in Devise Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, devise, warden

I have just begun with testing Devise. I am unable to understand of why i am getting this error ::

```
Failure/Error: subject.current_user.should_not be_nil
 ArgumentError:
   uncaught throw :warden
```

This is the code in my spec ::

```
    require "spec_helper"

    describe Devise::PasswordsController do
      include Devise::TestHelpers
        before(:each) do
            user = Factory(:user)
            @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
            sign_in user
        end
        it "should have a current user" do
                subject.current_user.should_not be_nil
        end
    end
```

Has anyone gotten a fix around this issue ? I know there are issues on `github` but in their case `include Devise::TestHelpers` was not present unlike in my case.

I am getting an error on this line :: `subject.current_user.should_not be_nil`

Comment: Did you find a fix for this problem?

Comment: @Zabba, ya, i just knocked off the user loading from the Factory and mainly, I did two things. ``1)`` Make Sure that this is not an integration test and ``2)`` call the function from the **ControllerMacros** ``login_user``

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I see this is a very old question, but I came across similar issue. This is what helped me.

If you're using `confirmable` module, don't forget to confirm user, otherwise the Warden exception is thrown. Appropriate change to your code would be:

```
before(:each) do
    user = Factory(:user)
    user.confirmed_at = Time.zone.now
    user.save
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    sign_in user
end
```

More info could be found in [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara)

Comment: BTW you can just do `user.confirm!` as shorthand for confirmed_at and saving.

Comment: Great find, this answer needs to be accepted @ktkaushik

Comment: I had some problem with the fixture: this one works https://gist.github.com/henrydjacob/1344451

Comment: @jbnunn Done ! close to 2 years late, but better late than never. Sorry. :)

Comment: If you use fixtures you can just add `confirmed_at: 2017-08-01` to your fixture for the model you are trying to `login_as`.

Comment: Add this to your factory.
`confirmed_at { Time.zone.now }`

Answer (score 4):

`uncaught throw :warden` happens when `authenticate_user!` fails.

Figure out why your the user's authentication is a failing, and you'll have solved your problem.