# How to implement RSpec session controller test with invalid user credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rspec, devise, tdd

I'm writing RSpec tests for my `SessionsController`. My tests work fine when testing `session#create` with *valid* credentials. However, I want to also write tests for what happens when the users credentials are *invalid*, such as redirecting back to the sign in page, setting a flash alert, etc. But for any of these tests, I'm getting an error:

```
1) SessionsController POST #create when password is INCORRECT
  Failure/Error: post :create, user: {username: 'Example', password: ''}
  ArgumentError:
    uncaught throw :warden
  # ./spec/support/default_params.rb:7:in `process_with_default_params'
  # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:24:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's my `sessions_controller_spec.rb` code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsController do
  before do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

  describe 'POST #create' do
    context "when password is INCORRECT" do
      let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: 'Example', password: 'Secr3t&$') }

      before(:each) do
        post :create, user: { username: 'Example', password: '' }
      end

      it { should set_the_flash[:alert].to('Invalid username or password.') }
      it { should respond_with(:redirect) }
      it { should redirect_to(:new_user_session) }
  end
end
```

Here's my `spec_helper.rb` code:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you double check that it is included in the test as well? I know it *should* be, based on your spec_helper, but I remember at least once when it was not automatically hooking up for me like you'd expect.

Comment: There was a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17541915/3507417

Answer (score 2):

I know it is too late now but in case this helps someone else: you need to add `setup_controller_for_warden` to your `before` block, so it becomes:

```ruby
before do
  @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  setup_controller_for_warden
end
```

Also it would be better to use the translation for you assertion. In rspec 3 format, the assertion should like this:

```ruby
expect(flash[:alert]).to eq(I18n.t('devise.failure.invalid'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the proper I18n check. If you're using custom authentication keys, you can parameterize it:  `expect(flash[:alert]).to eq(I18n.t('devise.failure.invalid', authentication_keys: 'Login'))`